# how enable the check box after disable?

Tags: javascript, html, function

i wrote code this i want to disable the input after check box has checked .it's OK i did that.another function is about when i click the input after that the check box has to disable .
my problem is if i want to click on check box then the check box enable after that .
this my code ;

```js
function clickcity() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("city-new-ad");
  var myinput = document.getElementById("select-city-ad");

  if (document.getElementById("city-new-ad").disabled == true) {
    document.getElementById("select-city-ad").disabled == true;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("city-new-ad").disabled == false) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("select-city-ad").disabled == true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("select-city-ad").disabled == false;
    }
  }
}

function clickphone() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("phone-ad");

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("another-phone").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("another-phone").disabled = false;
  }
}

function clickcity_option() {
  document.getElementById("city-new-ad").disabled = true;
}

function clickphone_option() {
  document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">phone number:</label>
  <span>my phone number</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="phone-ad" onclick="clickphone()">
  <br>
  <span class="my-phone-ne">another phone : </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-register"
      onclick="clickphone_option()" id="another-phone"
      style="border: 1px solid #370DFF; display: inline-block; width: 30% !important; margin-right: 5px !important;">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">address: </label>
  <span>my town</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="city-new-ad" onclick="clickcity()">
  <select class="custom-select select-search select-width"
      onclick="clickcity_option()" id="select-city-ad"
      style=" border: 1px solid #370DFF; width: 20%;">
      <option selected
          style="overflow-wrap: break-word !important; text-align: center !important;">
          choose city</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually if a checkbox is disabled you don't want the user to click on it - so why are you trying to handle further clicks on it? Also you might want to check your statements. Sometimes you use `==` (which is a check for truthiness) when I think you meant `=` (which assigns a value)

Comment: You might also want to consider the [`onchange`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) event instead of onclick. Bear in mind though that this won't fire on a disabled checkbox.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but you know i want both side for example when the check disable and i click on it then enabled and the select changing to disable

Comment: Is this any closer to what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/3xgzpm1w/

Comment: no,when click on option i want enable it when disabled by select . your code like my code  see when you click on phone input the check has disabled but i want when i click on check box and enable it .

Comment: So let me get this right, you want the phone field and the select to start disabled. You can enable and disable both of them by their linked checkbox, and you can always check or uncheck both checkboxes?

Comment: yes that's right for example you are the user and you have two option first select your phone you have added in your account so you can't use the input and then it's disable or the user want to use another phone number then click on input and write the new number the main problem is when the user change mind and want it use the number added before he can't because the check box has gone and need to refresh the page so i don't want this happen i want the users return and check that box use their own number .

Comment: it's not about city it;s about phone field

Comment: if the phone going to fix the city will change it

Answer (score 0):

made changes in HTML added onkeyup instead of onclick

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-register" onkeyup="clickphone_option(this)" id="another-phone" style=" border:1px solid #370DFF; display: inline-block; width: 30% !important ;margin-right: 5px !important;">
```

In js clickphone_option function added a if condition, which checks if input vale is > 0 if its > 0 it will disable checkbox and if you backspace all value of checkbox it will enable checkbox again.

```
function clickphone_option(a) {
        if(a.value.lenght>0){
        document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = true;
        }else{
        document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: why you used value??

Comment: if you enter some value in textbox only checkbox will be disabled, otherwise checkbox is enabled.. basically if a value is entered in textbox checkbox gets disabled and if the value entered is removed then checkbox gets enabled again

Comment: in this anwser function clickphone_option(a) {
        if(a.value.lenght>0){
        document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = true;
        }else{
        document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = false;

        }
    }   if the else working it solved

Comment: else is working for me.. can you copy paste the code and check again

Comment: so the main problem is if i want check the box after i write something and then delete it with back space .it was disable and the user can't modified .

Comment: There has to be some condition to enable checkbox which is disabled.....

Comment: can you write this condition because i wrote that you can see my code but it doesn't work

Comment: you have written condition only for checkbox, you should write some condition in input type to solve this.

Comment: this is only function i'v written for input :function clickphone_option() {
  document.getElementById("phone-ad").disabled = true;
}